# How do I get the key's value after I release the key

Tags: autohotkey

I understand by using for example,

```
Space & a::b
```

I can have `b` by holding `Space` then press `a`. However this disable the `Space`'s output. How do I get a `Space` character, for example by releasing `Space` key or press `Space` key twice.

Comment: See [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind Space to send itself:

```
Space & a::b
Space::Send {Space}
```

I would advise against using a common key as a prefix, however: a prefix key will lose any "on press" and repeat capabilities.  So with this script, Space won't write many spaces, only one, and only on release (and you'll wonder for a while why can't you bunny hop in your fav game anymore, *every* time!).

Just typing text feels awkward right now, the slight delay after every space causing mistakes.

I'd recommend at least using a whitelist to restrict the hotkey to the programs where you need it:

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#IfWinActive "i)notepad|word|thunderbird"
Space & a::b
Space::Send {Space}
```

Or some such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#If GetKeyState("Space")
a::b
```

Comment: Thanks. When I hold the `Space` key, it prints some `Space` characters until I press `a` key. I prefer holding `Space`, prints nothing until a key is pressed.

Comment: That's the behavior your program had, right? If this answer solved your problem, please accept it.